# Constraint generic type for enum type to implement some interface

Tags: java, generics, enums

I have enum that implement MyInterface.
While making other class using that enum I want to constrain the enumClz to be class that has implemented MyInterface.

So I describe signature to be "`T extends Enum< T extends MyInterface>`" at generic type declaration.

```
public <T extends Enum< T extends MyInterface>> C1( Class<T> enumClz) {
    for (T anEnumConst : enumClz.getEnumConstants()) {
        //....process
    }
}
```

What surprised me is the IDE say it is "unexpected bound" at "`T extends MyInterface`".
I don't know what it means by such two word error message, Any solution about this?

---

And by the way, out of curious I have an odd question though not really important. 
Can an enum type T be equivalent to the following infinite loop

`<T extends Enum< T extends Enum<T extends<....>>>>`        ?

Comment: @alfasin `extends` when used in generic bounds means "is, or extends, or implements".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declare the following instead:

```
public <T extends Enum<T> & MyInterface> C1(Class<T> enumClz)
```

Here, we're declaring `T` to have multiple upper bounds, which is possible for type parameters.

The declaration `<T extends Enum<T extends MyInterface>>` is invalid syntax because `T` must be bounded with a concrete type, but the `T extends MyInterface` in the type argument for `Enum` is trying to add more information about `T` when it's already been declared.

Note also that a class type must always come first when declaring multiple bounds. A declaration of `<T extends MyInterface & Enum<T>>` is also invalid syntax.

> And by the way, out of curious I have an odd question though not really important. Can an enum type `T` be equivalent to the following infinite loop
>
> `<T extends Enum< T extends Enum<T extends<....>>>>` ?

The declaration `T extends Enum<T>` is already "infinite" in that it's *recursive*. The same `T` that is being declared is given as a type argument for its upper bound - a type parameter's scope includes its own declaration.

More information:

- [Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)
- [Can I use a type parameter as part of its own bounds?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Can%20I%20use%20a%20type%20parameter%20as%20part%20of%20its%20own%20bounds%20or%20in%20the%20declaration%20of%20other%20type%20parameters?)
- [How do I decrypt "`Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`"?](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ106)

Comment: Is symbol `&` supported in java 6?